# Find liminf of $(-1-\frac{2}{n})^n$

Tags: real-analysis

I'm trying to find 
$$\liminf_{n\to\infty}\left(-1-\frac{2}{n}\right)^n$$
I know the answer is $-e^2$ and I know how to get $e^2$ but I don't know where does the the minus sign come from. Anyone can help me with it? Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$(-1-\frac{2}{n})^n=(-1)^n\left[(1+\frac{2}{n})^{n/2}\right]^2$. Thus taking the liminf sends the $(-1)^n$ to $-1$.

Comment: So, if I didn't get it wrong, you mean if this problem is asking for limsup, it should be $e^2$ instead of $-e^2$? i.e. $(-1)^n$ to 1?

Comment: @Kelan that is correct. As mentioned in the other answer, this sequence has two converging subsequences, one to each of $\pm e^2$

Answer (score 1):

The sequence $\left((-1-2/n)^n\right)_{n=1}^\infty$ is the result of interweaving two sequences,
$$ \left(-(1+\frac{2}{n})^n\right)_{n=1}^\infty,\left((1+\frac{2}{n})^n\right)_{n=1}^\infty
$$
They both converge but they don't converge when interweaved. The limit of the former sequence is the $\liminf$.